# Does Firestore through error or retries when write failed due to the 1 write per sec per document limitation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My project in Ionic 5. For example, if multiple users updating a Firestore document with the following value.

```
try{
  await this.afs.doc('path').update({ count: firestore.FieldValue.Increment(1)});
}catch (error) {
 ...
}
```

If the write of a user fails due to the Firestore limitation of 1 write per second per document, will the code be able to `catch` it as an error. Also, will Firestore retry that failed write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will generate an error you can catch.  No, it will not be retried.

Comment: They removed the write limit. What can we expect now if we send several writes in a short time? Are they guaranteed to run now?